# mysql group by keeping the more recent date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+------------+--------+-----+
|  reg_dat   | status | id  |
+------------+--------+-----+
| 2016-01-31 |     10 |   1 |
| 2017-06-31 |     12 |   1 |
| 2015-01-31 |     12 |   4 |
| 2017-01-25 |      5 |   4 |
| 2017-01-11 |      3 |   2 |
+------------+--------+-----+
```

I would like to do a mysql query to group the rows by id and keeping only the more recent date... so the output should be the following:

```
+------------+--------+-----+
|  reg_dat   | status | id  |
+------------+--------+-----+
| 2017-06-31 |     12 |   1 |
| 2017-01-25 |      5 |   4 |
| 2017-01-11 |      3 |   2 |
+------------+--------+-----+
```

Unfortunately my code doesn't work...

```
select *
from table
group by id
order by id, reg_dat DESC
```

Have you some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using a JOIN and a subquery

```
SELECT t.reg_dat, t.status, t.id
FROM table t
JOIN (SELECT max(reg_dat) max_date, id FROM table GROUP BY id) t1
  ON t.reg_dat = t1.max_date AND t.id = t1.id
```